# convertir resultado del array a JSON

Tags: php, javascript, array, web, fetch

Dado el siguiente bucle, quiero convertir en **formato json** el siguiente **array**, para pasarlo al **objectJSON** de fecth de mi javascript.

Con la función json_encode no me funciona...

```
for($i = 0; $i < $longitudDePalabra; $i++) {
    $pos = strpos($palabra, $letra, $offset);

    if($pos === false){
        break;
    }

    $posiciones[] = "$pos";
    $offset = $pos + 1;
}
```

¿Alguien sabría como?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que tu array `$posiciones` contiene ya ciertos valores (los cuales no ejemplificaste pero damos por hecho que ya tienen información) y el objetivo es ocupar la función de php llamada `json_encode` (no `json_enconde`) y regresarlo adonde quieras (en este caso tú lo recibirás en algún código javascript como por ejemplo por `AJAX`) en este formato haríamos lo siguiente:

```
for($i=0;$i<$longitudDePalabra;$i++) {
   $pos=strpos($palabra,$letra,$offset);

   if($pos===false){
      break;
   }

   $posiciones[]="$pos";
   $offset = $pos + 1;    
}
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($posiciones, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Explico lo ocupado y adicionado:

1. La cabecera `header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');` nos va a servir para poder responder desde el servidor en un formato JSON nativo
2. Al hacer `echo json_encode($posiciones, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);` vamos a respoder un formato json o esa será la salida final.
3. El ocupar como segundo parámetro en la función `json_encode` el `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`
   nos permite poder leer de una manera más legible nuestro objeto JSON.

Como ejemplo, supongamos que tenemos tu array `$posiciones` con los siguientes valores:

```
$posiciones = array("clave_uno" => 1, "clave_dos" => 3, "clave_tres" => 4);
```

Entonces, al realizar lo siguiente:

```
<?php
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
$posiciones = array("clave_uno" => 1, "clave_dos" => 3, "clave_tres" => 4);
echo json_encode($posiciones, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Obtendríamos como salida esto:

```
{
    "clave_uno": 1,
    "clave_dos": 3,
    "clave_tres": 4
}
```

Al final, tu archivo .php con estas reglas siempre te regresará un objeto JSON válido de acuerdo a los valores o a la estructura de tu array inicial.

Como referencias, te dejo lo siguiente que ocupamos:

- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp

  https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php

  https://www.php.net/manual/es/json.constants.php